# slideshow jquery show all images on load

Tags: php, jquery, slideshow

I have a Slideshow with jquery. But when i add an hyperlink to the images the slider is displaying all the pictures in gallery on load.

Do i need to change the script?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var
      images = "#gallery  img" // image selector
    , interval = 4000           // milliseconds between transitions
    , index = 0                 // starting index
    , count = $(images).length  // image count
      // the transition loop
    , handle = setInterval(function() {
        // fade out the current image
        $(images + ":eq(" + index + ")").fadeOut('slow');
        // get the next index, or cycle back to 0
        if (++index === count) index = 0;
        // fade in the next image
        $(images + ":eq(" + index + ")").fadeIn('slow');
      }
      , interval
    )
    , stop = function(){
        clearInterval(handle);
    };
  });
  

</script>

 <div id="gallery">
 <a href="hyperlink"><img class="active" src="image"></a>
 <a href="hyperlink"><img src="image"></a>
 </div>
```